# How to write debugging helper for cdb in qt creator?

Tags: qt, gdb, qt-creator, cdb

We're switching from using GCC/GDB in our project to MSVC 2013/CDB but would still like to use Qt Creator as the IDE. One of the last remaining issues is that we have a few debug helpers written in Python for GDB for some really opaque internal data structures and we absolutely need a version of that we can use with CDB.

I've googled quite a bit and search qt forum, but haven't found a good starting point for how to tackle this.

Comment: If you install *Visual Studio Add-in for MSVC 2013*, it should display Qt data structure nicely when debugging using MSVC. The source code is available at [https://wiki.qt.io/Visual_Studio_Add-in#Get_the_sources](https://wiki.qt.io/Visual_Studio_Add-in#Get_the_sources). Maybe it could be your starting point.

Comment: I think you didn't understand question well enough.All I need is to write debug helper for qt creator not visual studio.

Comment: Ah sorry, I think you're moving to MSVC and you need the helper for CDB in MSVC, but what you need is in the qt creator side.

Comment: Then, the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-helpers.html) and qtcreator source code will be the starting point, e.g. debugger helper in [https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/tree/master/share/qtcreator/debugger](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/tree/master/share/qtcreator/debugger). If it doesn't help, please ignore my comment.

Comment: @putu Any way thanks for your responds those you mentioned are about for debug helpers in python for GDB. I want to have this feature for CDB as well. I've read documentation before ask any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Qt Creator 4.3 you can use exactly the same debugging helpers for GDB and CDB (and LLDB). The syntax has changed slightly compared to 4.2 but porting should be straightforward. It was mentioned in the release [blog](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/05/24/qt-creator-4-3-0-released/).

Comment: Sounds a good starting point , anyway at the moment I'm busy for some other issues.I will respond to this.